# changing perspective in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

When I do a plot3 and record a movie, I cannot decide the perspective that is recorded in movie at any point.

I don't want the default perspective that I get on screen. and I want to change. Is it possible to change it with plot parameters?

This is not code specific. Any plot3 will have this problem so I do not see an example necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`view`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/view.html) command will allow you to change the angle at which the plot is viewed.

For example,

```
surf(peaks)   % sample plot
az = 0;       % specify azimuth
el = 90;      % specify elevation
view(az,el)   % set viewing angle
```